# NetworkManager segfault every time I disconnect

Tags: network-manager, crash, segmentation-fault

Every time I disconnect from a wired or wireless network using the network manager applet, I get this in `dmesg`:

```
[ 2036.633608] NetworkManager[13108]: segfault at 8 ip 000000000048abc6 sp 00007ffddc984ce0 error 4 in NetworkManager[400000+2b8000]
```

Also the applet crashes, automatically restarts, and the network is automatically connected to again. (This makes it impossible to disconnect from a network without removing the connection or stopping network-manager manually).

The exact same thing happens on both my laptop and my desktop (they each run Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 0):

A crash is a bug. Make sure to use the latest version provided by your distribution. Please report the bug against your distribution.